# Use Rails STI model with join conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sti

I have the following models defined:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Policeman < Person
end

class Firefighter < Person
end
```

Inside `Group`, I would like to get all groups that have `Policemen`, for example:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policemen
  scope :with_policemen, -> { joins(:policemen).uniq }
end
```

This works as expected. Now if I want to grab all groups that have a `Policeman` that has `status: 3`, I would do:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policemen
  scope :with_policemen, -> { joins(:policemen).where(policemen: { status: 3 }).uniq }
end
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work, since ActiveRecord constructs the query using `policemen` table, which obviously doesn't exist. A solution would be to use `where(people: { status: 3 })` inside the scope, but I was wondering why can't ActiveRecord put the correct table in the WHERE clause, since it has the necessary associations set.

Comment: Yeah - this is where you just have to use the correct table name. It's probably 'people', so `where(people: {status: 3})`.  In logs, you can see what the sql is it generates and then see the sql error if you need to tweak it.

Comment: Indeed, I intended to write `people`. So isn't there any way for ActiveRecord to properly detect the correct table from the given association?

Comment: I think the only option is to use the table name here.

Comment: Then I guess you can post an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where), the format expected for the hash syntax is `table_name: { column_name: val }`.

```
scope :with_policemen, -> { joins(:policemen).where(people: { status: 3 }).uniq }
```

I agree with you - it would make more sense if the where and joins syntax were similar.  Another inconsistency - the `group` method doesn't take a hash, only a string or array.